# AsyncTask does not call onPostExecute()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an Android `AsyncTask` and `onPostExecute()` never runs.

Now, I KNOW my `doInBackground()` runs through because I tested that.

My `onPostExecute()` is this:

```
 protected void onPostExecute( ) {
    System.out.println("onPost");
    helper.close();
    System.out.println("worked");
    if (unitary && exists)    {  
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        System.out.println("notified");
    }
    }
```

None of the print line are printed.

Do I have to actually CALL that method somewhere?

Comment: Post your complete `AsyncTask` you aren't using any `params` in your declaration but it should have *something*

Comment: Where are you expecting System.out.println() to print?

Comment: And no, you don't have to call that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I have to actually CALL that method somewhere?

No, but you have to implement it properly.

Start by adding the `@Override` annotation to it. Always do this when you override a method (or implement a method defined on an interface).

Then, you will get a compile error, pointing out that your method does not actually override anything. That is because `onPostExecute()` always takes a parameter, of the third type in the `AsyncTask` declaration. So, if you are creating an `AsyncTask<Foo, Bar, Baz>`, `onPostExecute()` takes a `Baz` as a parameter.

Here is a sample implementation of a fragment using an `AsyncTask` to simulate downloading data in the background. It uses `Void` as the third data type in the `AsyncTask` declaration (per your comment), and therefore takes `Void` as the parameter to `onPostExecute()`:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2008-2014 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain   a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    http://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.async;

import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AsyncDemoFragment extends ListFragment {
  private static final String[] items= { "lorem", "ipsum", "dolor",
      "sit", "amet", "consectetuer", "adipiscing", "elit", "morbi",
      "vel", "ligula", "vitae", "arcu", "aliquet", "mollis", "etiam",
      "vel", "erat", "placerat", "ante", "porttitor", "sodales",
      "pellentesque", "augue", "purus" };
  private ArrayList<String> model=null;
  private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=null;
  private AddStringTask task=null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setRetainInstance(true);

    if (model == null) {
      model=new ArrayList<String>();
      task=new AddStringTask();
      task.execute();
    }

    adapter=
        new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                                 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                 model);
  }

  @Override
  public void onViewCreated(View v, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(v, savedInstanceState);

    getListView().setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    if (task != null) {
      task.cancel(false);
    }

    super.onDestroy();
  }

  class AddStringTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
      for (String item : items) {
        if (isCancelled())
          break;

        publishProgress(item);
        SystemClock.sleep(400);
      }

      return(null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... item) {
      if (!isCancelled()) {
        adapter.add(item[0]);
      }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
      if (!isCancelled()) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.done, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
             .show();
      }

      task=null;
    }
  }
}
```

(from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Threads/AsyncTask))

Comment: I now that, but my Baz is a Void. can I actually give that as a Parameter?

Comment: @newnewbie: Yes. `Void` is the, um, object form of `void`, and it can be a parameter to a method, just as it is the return type from your `doInBackground()` method. See [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Threads/AsyncTask), which uses `Void` for the third data type in the `AsyncTask` declaration.

Comment: Turns out, know, Void produces a compiler Error

Comment: Yep, @Override is one of the biggest saves you can have. You should be able to put a Void parameter but it can only ever be null

Comment: Turns out I can only accept the answer in 7 minutes...I will do it then. However, why did you have to DOWNVOTE me?

Comment: @newnewbie: I did not downvote you. Moreover, your question does not appear to have any downvotes at the present time.

Comment: sorry about that then. I thought I had seen a downvote.